# Synergy configuration with multiple X screens

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, synergy

I'm having a problem figuring out how to configure synergy to behave on a system with multiple X windows.

On my desktop I am running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. I have two monitors, setup as separate X screens by preference as well as to enable me to rotate the left-hand monitor.

I also have a laptop, which I have on the desk in front of me, lower than the other two monitors. I have a very simple synergy.conf:

```
section: screens
    desktop:
    laptop:
end

section: links
    desktop:
        down = laptop
    laptop:
        up = desktop
end
```

It works, but on the desktop only on whichever screen I run `synergys` from in terminal (I haven't set it up to run at startup yet because I've been playing with the configuration).

I can't find any information how to reference multiple screens on one system, and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. This worked for me.

On Server:
Create a synergy screen for each X screen (say L1 and L2).

On Client:
Run the client twice and each time use --display :0.0 and :0.1 respectively and --name to identify screen to server.

For example: `/usr/bin/synergyc --daemon --display :0.0 --name L1 [server]`

Comment: Two clients! That is super clever, it never even crossed my mind. Thank you!